# PHP MySQL File upload only working occasionally

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have written a script to allow the user in the back end to upload pictures for the gallery. The script is supposed to upload the file to the server and then post the file name and info into the database.

It always uploads the file to the server without fail, however for some reason it only posts it to the database occasionally. Sometimes it works fine but 8 times out of 10 it uploads the file and thats it, the script is as follows.

```
<?php  

 //This is the directory where images will be saved  
 $target = "images/";  
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);  

 //This gets all the other information from the form  
 $name=$_POST['name'];  
 $caption=$_POST['caption'];  
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);  
 $live=$_POST['live']; 

 //Connecting to the database 
 require_once('../Connections/tim.php');  


 //Writes the information to the database  
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gallery` VALUES ('$name', '$caption', '$pic', '$live')") ;  

 //Writes the photo to the server  
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))  
 {  

 //Tells you if its all ok  
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded successfully, press back to upload more";  
 }  
 else {  

 //Gives and error if its not  
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Almost total lack of error handling: You assume the upload succeeded, you assume the DB query succeed; you're wide open to SQL injection attacks, you don't filter the files being uploaded, so anyone can upload anything they want and have it executed on your server, etc... in short, this code is a security disaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should read something on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and you **should use PDO or mysqli** (as [jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12845830/1149736)) suggested.

But debugging at your situation could be done by this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gallery` VALUES ('$name', '$caption', '$pic', '$live')") ;  
if( mysql_errno() != 0){
     // mysql error
     // note: message like this should never appear to user, should be only stored in log
     echo "Mysql error: " . htmlspecialchars( mysql_error());
     die();
}
```

And you have to escape your database inputs at least by [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I am new to PHP and MySQL so really appreciate your help on this. I have added the code in and now when I press upload it says "Mysql error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" not quite sure what this means? thanks again

Comment: @JamesLeist it means that table `gallery` has 3,5,6,... enything but 4 columns.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because of the sql injection hole you have: If a caption (or any other posted field) contains for example a `'`, it will break your query.

You should dump the `mysql_*` functions and switch to prepared statements with PDO or mysqli. And always add error handling.

Comment: Or at least use `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: There are some situations (I'm not saying they are good or desired in "real world", but they just happens) when transforming whole application (some large portals, enterprise applications, applications that run on outdated systems) into modern, new and safe way isn't an option :( . I find it worth to mention "broken, deprecated solutions" just for sake of those. But you're right, this isn't the way it should be. +1

Comment: @Vyktor True, I'm probably just getting tired of all these `mysql_*` questions here. Still wouldn't recommend it though :-)